# Update ViewModel after dynamically updating the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I am trying to define ViewModels that faithfully represent the view (to make strict use of that concept).

Some of the elements of the ViewModel are updated dynamically. The problem I have, is that when I do the Post, the ViewModel returns without the elements that were updated dynamically.

The update is done through jQuery, when an event is performed. An action is invoked through Url.Action, and a Div is updated.

I made an example to clarify the scenario. An application that only stores a location (state and city). For this I have three ViewModels: one to represent the States in a SelectList, one to represent the Cities in a SelectList, and finally one to represent the Location (formed by the two ViewModel that I mentioned first).

Models:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class CitySelectListViewModel
{
    public CitySelectListViewModel() { }
    public CitySelectListViewModel(IEnumerable<Models.City> cities)
    {
        this.Cities = cities;
    }
    [Display(Name = "Cities")]
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; }
}

public class StateSelectListViewModel
{
    public StateSelectListViewModel() { }
    public StateSelectListViewModel(IEnumerable<State> states)
    {
        this.States = states;
    }
    [Display(Name = "States")]
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedStateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; }
}

public class LocationCreateViewModel
{
    public LocationCreateViewModel() { }
    public LocationCreateViewModel(ICollection<State> states)
    {
        this.StateSelectListViewModels = new StateSelectListViewModel(states);
        this.CitySelectListViewModel = new CitySelectListViewModel();
    }
    public StateSelectListViewModel StateSelectListViewModels { set; get; }
    public CitySelectListViewModel CitySelectListViewModel { set; get; }
}
```

Location [Controller]:

```
public class LocationController : Controller
{
    private DALDbContext db = new DALDbContext();

    // GET: Location/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        LocationCreateViewModel locationCreateViewModel = new LocationCreateViewModel(db.States.ToList());
        return View(locationCreateViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(LocationCreateViewModel pLocationCreateViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.States.Add(state);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        LocationCreateViewModel locationCreateViewModel = new LocationCreateViewModel(db.States.ToList());
        return View(locationCreateViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult CitySelectList(int? stateId)
    {
        CitySelectListViewModel citySelectListViewModel = new CitySelectListViewModel(db.Cities.Where(c => c.StateId == stateId).ToList());
        return View(citySelectListViewModel);
    }
}
```

Create [View]:

```
@model ViewModelExample.ViewModels.LocationCreateViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>State</h4>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateSelectListViewModels.SelectedStateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateSelectListViewModels.SelectedStateId, new SelectList(Model.StateSelectListViewModels.States, "Id", "Name"), "Select a State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "StateSelectList" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateSelectListViewModels.SelectedStateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="CityContainer">
            @Html.Action("CitySelectList")
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Fill City DropDownList
            $('#StateSelectList').change(function () {
                var selectedStateId = this.value;
                $('#CityContainer').load('@Url.Action("CitySelectList")?stateId=' + selectedStateId);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

CitySelectList [View]:

```
@model ViewModelExample.ViewModels.CitySelectListViewModel
....
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "Id", "Name"), "Select a City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I will show the execution of my example, and I will show the problem through the inspection of the ViewModel that I receive after the Post:

1. I select a State and a City, and I press Create.
   [image: Example image Number 1]
2. I inspect the ViewModel received after the Post. We can see how CitySelectListViewModel is null, and **what I want is to bring the last ViewModel that was updated through jQuery**.

[image: Example image Number 2]

I admit that I have provided a long example, but it is the only way I found to explain what I need. Thanks in advance.

[VS-Project of the example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ctbvfzhji1xz1d/ViewModelExample.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Can you store it in a hidden field?

Comment: @KevinCook Not in this case. I have approximately 2400 records. I need the application to be as light as possible. (Thanks for your incredibly fast response!)

Comment: Have you considered storing the records in the cache?

Comment: @KevinCook For the same reason I mentioned earlier, I would like to send as little data as possible. Is there no way to dynamically update the ViewModel?

Comment: Because your 2nd dropdownlist has `name="SelectedCityId"` but it needs to be `name="CitySelectListViewModel .SelectedCityId"` in order to bind to your model. But you taking the the wrong approach and over complicating it. There are also other issues why your code will not work correctly, including you loose the data in the 2nd dropdownlist when returning the view is `ModelState` is invalid. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to correctly implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am precisely looking for a way to be simpler and more orderly, and mainly, not to repeat myself. I will study the example that you suggest to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ts because you are preventing the modelBinder to accurately bind to `LocationCreateViewModel` in your `Create` action when replacing the inner HTML of  `<div id="CityContainer">` (thats what you do with `$('#CityContainer').load(...`). You instruct the model binder to bind to 
@model ViewModelExample.ViewModels.CitySelectListViewModel and as a result you get this HTML for the city select list:

[image]

One way of solving this is modifying `CitySelectList.cshtml` to:

```
@model ViewModelExample.ViewModels.LocationCreateViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CitySelectListViewModel.SelectedCityId, 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
model.CitySelectListViewModel.SelectedCityId, new 
SelectList(Model.CitySelectListViewModel.Cities, "Id", "Name"), "Select a City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CitySelectListViewModel.SelectedCityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and your `CitySelectList` action to:

```
 public ActionResult CitySelectList(int? stateId)
    {
        LocationCreateViewModel locationCreateViewModel = new LocationCreateViewModel();
        locationCreateViewModel.CitySelectListViewModel = new CitySelectListViewModel(db.Cities.Where(c => c.StateId == stateId).ToList());

        return View(locationCreateViewModel);
    }
```

But I would recommend [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) as well.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem.

I find myself with another problem, I do not want to repeat myself. I want to make reusable components, and the strategy that you mention to me, forces me to repeat the Views and the Controllers.

Now I am studying the Custom ViewModel that you suggested to me.

If you have more ideas to achieve what I am looking for, I am all hearing. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, custom model binding would prevent you from repeating yourself but I don't think I would recommend creating a custom binder for every model in your project. Maybe you should check your viewmodels models and design them in a way that _helps_ binding. An other way coud be what @kevincook suggested, you could store the selected value of `selectedCityId` in a hidden field whose `name` attribute would make it accesible to the property of the model you try to bind.

Comment: There are many ways of approaching this issue and [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) could be one of them. But it all depends on the _bigger picture_ of your project.